# Help - How can I help rescue this young stray kitten?

Tags: cats, behavior, training, safety, psychology

So there's this young stray kitten (can run and eat solid food) that got stuck outside our window on the 3rd floor of an apartment building.

We helped bring her down and brought her inside the house (and gave her food), but being a stray cat, she was naturally very afraid and not trusting of humans and when I let go she ran up the staircase and went to the roof.

I went to the roof to get her but she kept running away, never letting me get to her.

So I just left her there with some food, thinking that after some rest she'd naturally walk down the staircase and go outside the building.

But a day later, I heard her meowing from the roof so I went there. Upon seeing me, she quickly ran and hid inside a small shed on the roof.

I even tried laying a trail of food all the way from the roof down the stairs and outside the building, so she could follow and find her way out, but it didn't seem to work.

There are no food or water sources on the roof, so she can't live there. But I'm not sure if she's intentionally not leaving, or if she wants to leave but can't. She can definitely just walk across the roof and down the stairs to leave the building, and most of the time there are no humans on this path, but I'm confused as to why she isn't leaving still.

How can I help her get down and out of the building? We live in a small town and there aren't any pet/animal shelters or assistance nearby.

Would love some advice from you guys...

Comment: you have teached the kitten that there is food on the roof of the building,if you got the option food on the roof or starvation on the street had you stayed on the street?

Comment: @trondhansen That's not the problem, even if I don't give the kitten food/water she just stays on the roof, not walking out even though the path is open. In other words, it seems that even if she's starving, for some reason she still won't leave the roof to go look for food. I need the kitten to learn how to leave the building, as I can't always be there to care for her, even though I wish I could.

Comment: This looks like a more technical problem than a pet problem. We might still help but you need to include some photos of the staircase and the roof. Otherwise there is just one simple solution: call the firefighters